# Is there a way to print the APDU command generated by NFCISO7816APDU

Tags: swift, nfc, ios13

I want to debug the following code and see what is the raw APDU it produces. I mean byte by byte from the header to the Le parameter.

```
let selectFileAPDU = NFCISO7816APDU(
    instructionClass: 0x0C,
    instructionCode: 0xA4,
    p1Parameter: 0x02,
    p2Parameter: 0x0C,
    data: selectFileCommand,
    expectedResponseLength: -1)
```